# Run App in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator, device

I have one Demo app download from developer.apple.com

I have problme that this app is only Run in device not in simulator,
It is may be becuase of some build setting.

Here I have attached one image to show it is not showing any simulator selection

[image]

Does any one know how to solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cant understand :( select simulator instead of device

Comment: Check the downloads tab in Xcode preferences, it seems to be a common problem that Xcode 4.3 has not been installing the simulator for some users. There will be install links for 5.1, 5.0, and 4.3 simulators in the downloads section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the string "iphonesimulator" in Supported Platforms on your build settings. So the strings "iphonesimulator" and "iphoneos" must both be present in the above to enable deploying on both device and simulator.

[image]

Comment: If it answered your question correctly, kindly consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

you must add platform support in build settings -> supported platform -> iphonesimulator